# Keyboard is not responding after implementing UISearchBar delegate method

Tags: iphone, uisearchbar, uisearchbardelegate

I have an `UISearchBar` which i implemented in my `viewDidLoad`: by code.
I have also set the `UISearchBarDelegate`.

Now i want to restrict the user from entering more than 5 chracter So i implement this delegate method

```
- (BOOL)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{

    NSLog(@"shouldChangeTextInRange");

    if (searchBar.text.length >= 5)
        return NO;

    return YES;
}
```

Its working fine.

The problem is when i typed upto 5 chracters & try to use the keyboard Backspace character, it is not working.

Also now if i pressed Search button in keyboard the `searchBarSearchButtonClicked`: is not getting called.

I am currently using

XCode version :3.2.5

iOS SDK :4.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do your test on the **new** text length (then length of the text that you will have if the suggested text change is applied), **not** the actual text length.

For that, you first need to compute the new text :

```
- (BOOL)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    if ([text isEqualToString:@"\n"])
        return YES; // accept validation button

    NSString* newText = [searchBar.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:text];

    if (newText.length >= 5)
        return NO;

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: But why searchBarSearchButtonClicked: is not getting called when i reach the end character?

Comment: Is it called correctly if you don't implement ```searchBar:shouldChangeTextInRange:```? Anyway, you probably need to ```return YES``` also ```if  ([text isEqualToString:@"\n"])```.

Comment: Yes it is getting called if i do not implement shouldChangeTextInRange:

Comment: Then I edited my answer, check and validate if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use backspace because of your code. after typing 5 characters, your searchBar is stuck. Use it instead :

```
    if ([textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length > 5) {
        return NO;
    }
```

Comment: But why searchBarSearchButtonClicked: is not getting called when i reached the end character?