# how to restrict input in UISearchBar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar

i'm new in Objective C, i have search bar in my tableView. I need no restrict input in my searchBar text field, for example i don't need to input more then 20 symbols, how can i do these?

in

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
```

i try to write smth like

```
searchBar.text.lenght == 20;
```

but it's no use

how can i do these? or maybe it easier to turn off keyboard when lenght>20. Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use `shouldChangeCharactersInRange:`

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
   return ([textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length > 20) ? NO : YES;
}
```

**Edit:**
Sorry. For UISearchBar you have to use

```
- (BOOL)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {
   return ([searchBar.text length] + [text length] - range.length > 20) ? NO : YES;
}
```

**Edit:**
See comment below

```
- (BOOL)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {
   return ([searchBar.text length] + [text length] - range.length <= 20);
}
```

Comment: The searchBarButtonClicked-Method would not called if I test that and reach the maximum char count. This works better for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7317394/701900

Comment: just a stylistic thing: NO : YES is a bit ugly. why not test for <= 20 and drop the ? NO : YES

Answer (score 4):

For future reader, in Swift 4:

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    let totalCharacters = (searchBar.text?.appending(text).count ?? 0) - range.length
    return totalCharacters <= 20
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on the other answer, since you are new to Objective-C

1.You will need to implement the UISearchBarDelegate protocol inside your view controller.

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UISearchBarDelegate>
```

2. You will need to assign the delegate

```
searchBar.delegate = self
```

3. Implement the delegate callback as specified in the other post

If you want to hide the keyboard if you go over 20 characters, you can do it in the same delegate function by calling

```
[searchBar resignFirstResponder];
```